# Getting jquery one() to work with repeated classes

Tags: jquery, html

Here is our HTML:

```
<div class="selecter-options">
    <span class="selecter-item" data-value="8">ABC</span>
    <span class="selecter-item" data-value="11">DEF</span>
    <span class="selecter-item selected" data-value="12">GHI</span>
    <span class="selecter-item" data-value="7">JKL</span>
    <span class="selecter-item selected" data-value="19">MNO</span>
</div>
```

And here our jQuery:

```
$('.selecter-item').one('click touch',
    function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
})
```

We are using jQuery to remove all '.selected' classes from our html when any '.selecter-item' is clicked. The jQuery should only fire the first time ANY '.selecter-item' element has been clicked.

How do we get jQuery to removeClass('selected') only once IRRESPECTIVE of which .selector-item is clicked on?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: When you do `$('.selecter-item').one`, you are binding the event to *all* `.selecter-item` elements.  So, they *each* have a one-time event bound to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/), it removes an event handler.

```
$('.selecter-item').one('click touch',function () {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

    //Remove event handler
    $('.selecter-item').off('click touch');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJdVx/1/)

Comment: +1 Good solution. I slightly modified your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/RJdVx/2/) adding a console event just to prove that the event fires only once.